# Binary to Decimal conversion theory

Tags: c++, math, binary, decimal, theory

So I have seen the following solution for binary to decimal conversion around, and I can see that it works, but I'd really like to understand the theory of the algorithm.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long bin, dec = 0, rem, num, base = 1;

    cout << "Enter the binary number(1s and 0s) : ";
    cin >> num;
    bin = num;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        rem = num % 10;
        dec = dec + rem * base;
        base = base * 2;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    cout << "The decimal equivalent of " << bin << " : " << dec << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So we are adding the remainder of the shifted input and multiplying it by the base of the position, but I don't really understand how this ends up adding up to the correct answer.

Let me know if there is anything I can provide to help.

Thanks

Comment: You should step through the code with the debugger so you can see how it works.  Or do it on pencil and paper.  Doing that should give you a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Hint: In reality `cin >> num` reads a decimal number representation from user input, not a binary representation. This looks like a very complicated way to read a `std::string` of binary representation and pass it to [`std::bitset`'s constructor.

Comment: one key point is that `rem` is `1` or `0`. This function iterates from the lower bits of `num` to the higher bits and it builds the number `bin` from its decomposition in base 2.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning `num` holds a binary representation of the number, but IT IS a base 10 number (eg: 1011 is a thousand and eleven).

The line `rem = num % 10;` take the last significant digit of the pseudo-binary number using the reminder of the division by decimal 10 (ten).

`dec = dec + rem * base;` add the weight of the digit (base) at the decimal representation.

`base = base * 2;` update the weight of the next digit (1,2,4,8,...).

`num = num / 10;` discard the last digit of the binary representation, equivalent to 1-digit right shift.

Answer (score 0):

In any base, a number equals the sum of its digits, each weighted by a power of the base.

For instance, in the decimal base, 4734 = 4.10³ + 7.10² + 3.10 + 4.1. This formula lets you convert from the digits to the internal integer representation. You can do it right to left, maintaining a temporary variable with the current power of the base (1, 10, 100...).

The converse operation, integer to digits, is achieved as follows:

- the last digit is the number modulo 10, i.e. 4734 % 10 = 4
- the number with the last digit dropped is the quotient by 10, i.e. 4734 / 10 = 473.

In the given algorithm, the input is in fact **a decimal number** with only digits 0/1. The algorithm extracts the digits one by one from right to left (base 10) and recombines them as **a binary number** in the internal representation.

For example,

1100 gives the digits 1, 1, 0, 0 which are recombined with the powers 1, 2, 2²=4, 2³=8, giving the total 4+8 = 12.

---

Actually, the `cout` statement will perform a binary-to-decimal conversion that yields the digits 2, 1 and output them, reversed.